# Openconnect Server not see my local network

Tags: networking, 22.04, vpn, openconnect

I has a vps that has ip `1.1.1.1`. this vps has two interface. one of theme inside my LAN by ip 10.10.10.2\24 as name eth1 and another side in internet (1.1.1.1) as ens33.

Now, i create a ocserver based [This Toutrial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openconnect-vpn-server-ocserv-ubuntu-20-04-lets-encrypt) and connection is ok. but when i connect to this i dont see any other device in LAN. i test it via PING. i think i have problem in my route or NAT.

need help for it. thx.

Comment: Your VPN subnet cannot be the same as your LAN subnet.  I would recommend changing your 10.10.10.2/24 network to something else like 10.0.0.2/24

Comment: Thx for your answer, i also used that by 192.168.101.0/24 but no answer. i test it again.

Comment: You shouldn't use IP 1.1.1.1 either as your VPS as that is actually assigned to Cloudflare.  I don't know what you actually have done because you are not providing the text output of what you have setup.  You only provided the instructions you followed, but in there is a lot of information about how your network and a VPS should be configured.  According to that documentation you should use different IP subnets for the VPS than you should be using on your home network.  I would recommend that you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1495159/edit) your question showing your configurations.